# Sorting NSDate with custom compare function

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sorting, nsdate

I have an array of dates. These dates are all NSString objects. Now I want to sort them. This is how my function looks like.

```
NSComparisonResult dateSort(NSString *s1, NSString *s2, void *context) {
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];

    NSString *date1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",s1];
    NSString *date2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",s2];

    NSDate *v1 = [df dateFromString: date1];
    NSDate *v2 = [df dateFromString: date2];
   return [v1 compare:v2];

}
```

And I call the function like this.

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [unsortedKeys sortedArrayUsingFunction:dateSort context:nil];
```

This is the result

```
sorted keys are (
    "24-10-2013",
    "28-06-2013",
    "03-10-2013",
    "20-12-2013",
    "04-09-2013",
    "19-09-2013",
    "07-07-2013",
    "15-09-2013",
    "01-07-2013",
    "04-11-2013",
    "27-06-2013",
    "02-10-2013",
    "05-08-2013",
    "17-10-2013",
    "04-10-2013"
)
```

This is not the correct order, I want them to descending.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: The date format is wrong, it should be `"dd-MM-yyyy"`. - There must be *many* duplicate questions and answers.

Comment: Try using `dd-MM-yyyy` for the format. And what is the point of the `date1` and `date2` variables? Why not directly use `s1` and `s2`?

Comment: Do you want just to change ascending to descending?

Comment: Why are your date keys kept as strings? Why not use actual dates for the keys? Eventually you may want to show them to the user and showing dates in the format `dd-MM-yyyy` to many users around the world will confuse them because that is not standard at all in many countries.

Comment: Remark: The date formatter should be created only once, and not for each call of the comparison function.

Comment: @MartinR The yyyy did the trick. When I create an instance variable of NSDateFormatter I can't call it in the NSComparision funtion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues:

- The correct date format is `"dd-MM-yyyy"`.
- To order the dates descending instead of ascending, just replace

  ```
  return [v1 compare:v2];
  ```

  by

  ```
  return [v2 compare:v1];
  ```
- The `stringWithFormat` calls are completely unnecessary (as commented by @rmaddy).
- Creating a date formatter is considered an expensive operation, it should be done only once.

With all that, your compare method should look like this:

```
NSComparisonResult dateSort(NSString *s1, NSString *s2, void *context) {
    static NSDateFormatter *df;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    });

    NSDate *v1 = [df dateFromString: s1];
    NSDate *v2 = [df dateFromString: s2];
    return [v2 compare:v1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Got a better understanding of the NSComparisonResult now and about the dispatch! Thanks dude !